# Vite Parse Error While Importing a React Component

Tags: reactjs, vite, parse-error, shopify-hydrogen

I'm trying Shopify's new framework - Hydrogen, which uses Vite. It's something like NextJS.

This is the `index.server.jsx` file:

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout.server";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>
          Hello world!
        </h1>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

And this is what the `Layout.server.js` file looks like:

```
export default function Layout({children}) {

  return (
    <div>
      ${children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I don't import and use Layout component, everything works fine.

But when using Layout, this error happens:

[image]

Any ideas on how this can be solved and what may be causing this ?
I think error message is not descriptive enough

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem was the extension of `Layout.server.js` file, which should've been `.jsx`. But still don't know why, so please let me know if you know